# Extract Integer value from string attribute in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an attribute in MYSQL table "primaryCamera", which has value as

```
Camera 8 MP, 3264 x 2448 pixels, Carl Zeiss optics, optical image stabilization, autofocus, dual
```

I want to list mobiles greater than or equal to 8MP, what is exact query in MYSQL which works for me.

Please help me.

Comment: I was looking for "LIKE", but this is not good. Any regular expression needed.

Comment: `Camera 8 MP` or `Camera 9 MP` is what you want to fetch and `Camera 7 MP` is not. Does this column all like this format `Camera X MP`?

Comment: This column has various numbers, such as 9MP, 3MP , 12MP. I need a query, which is used from less than or greater than a number. Such as i Have query. SELECT `primaryCamera` FROM table_name WHERE `primaryCamera` REGEXP '[8]' It work fine. But there are also some other integer in column. As mentioned above. What can i do

Comment: You didn't get it. Are all your data under `primaryCamera` column in this format  `Camera X MP..........................................`? @razaulmustafa

Comment: Yes. I have data, as you said. Please give me query now

Comment: Did you want this: `SELECT primaryCamera FROM table_name WHERE primaryCamera REGEXP '[0-9]*' `?

Answer (score 1):

If the data under `primaryCamera` column are in the following format then the query given below might do the job.

**Format:** `Camera X MP.....`

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
primaryCamera
FROM table_name 
WHERE 
CAST(SUBSTRING(@str FROM LOCATE('Camera',@str)+LENGTH('Camera') FOR (LOCATE('MP',@str)-(LOCATE('Camera',@str)+LENGTH('Camera')))) AS UNSIGNED) > 8;
```

**Explanation:**

- `LOCATE('Camera',@str)` returns the start index of the string
  `Camera`.
- `LENGTH('Camera')` returns the length of the string `Camera` which is
  `6`.
- `(LOCATE('MP',@str)` returns the start index of the string `MP`.

**Example:**

Given,

`primaryCamera = 'Camera 8 MP, 3264 x 2448 pixels, Carl Zeiss optics, optical image stabilization, autofocus, dual'`

startIndex of string `Camera` = 1

Length of `Camera` = 6

start Index of string `MP` = `10`.

The integer value you are looking for lies within this range `[7,10]`.

`SUBSTRING(string FROM START_INDEX_OF_DESIRED_SUBSTRING FOR LENGTH_YOU_WANT_TO_EXTRACT)` works like this.`

In order to get that you need to do this:

`START_INDEX_OF_DESIRED_SUBSTRING = StartIndex of Camera + Length of Camera`

`LENGTH_YOU_WANT_TO_EXTRACT = Start position of string`MP`- START_INDEX_OF_DESIRED_SUBSTRING`

`SUBSTRING(primaryCamera FROM START_INDEX_OF_DESIRED_SUBSTRING FOR LENGTH_YOU_WANT_TO_EXTRACT );`

**Note:** You should store the attributes of your product (e.g. Camera) in different columns under different table. Otherwise you are soon going to embrace lot of cumbersome tasks to process even for the simplest task.

Comment: This is not working. Can you please re-write this to this format. 8MP.  I don't have "Camera" in the beginning

Comment: Show me one real data under `primaryCamera` column.

Comment: SELECT `primary` FROM specifications_new_vastgsm WHERE LOCATE('MP',`primary`) and `primary`>=8.....This work for me

Comment: Show me one of the data under `primaryCamera` column as it is in your table please.

Comment: @1000111 I really really really think this is not a good question:D

Comment: which one @Reno? (:p) I am asking for one real data / the question posted here by the PO?

Comment: @1000111 Sorry, I mean the question itself.:( Author did not get what you said and can not make this question more clearly.

Comment: I got your point @Reno. I am still looking forward to knowing what exactly going on the mind inside of the PO. :p

Answer (score 0):

use sub string, the syntax is :

SELECT SUBSTR('string',start,length)

replace string here with your query

Comment: Please give me query. I have attribute PrimaryCamera and i want to select mobiles which have camera greater than 8MP.